# How to cast DATE type to REAL in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to convert DATE type to REAL before using AVG(). But my query results only years in dates. Here is an example.

```
sqlite> SELECT my_date FROM my_table;
2013-04-01
2013-04-25
sqlite> SELECT CAST(my_date AS REAL) FROM my_table;
2013.0
2013.0
```

Comment: what should be your expected out put on `SELECT CAST(my_date AS REAL) FROM my_table;` on you example?

Comment: I expect something that can be further used in AVG(). For example "SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(my_date AS REAL)) AS DATE) FROM my_table GROUP BY my_id;". Because I want to find an average date, when I call this command, the result is only 2013.0.

Comment: What is your idea behind the calculation of an "average date"?

Comment: Please read the [fine documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Thanks so much. After studying on http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html, I've found the solution by using date and time functions instead of casting. So I can run the following command and get desired results.

`SELECT datetime(AVG(strftime('%s',my_date)) FROM my_table GROUP BY my_id;`